# Java draw geometric figures using a variable

Tags: java

Ok, I am coding a Snake game and I wanna keep it rather simple, so I am opting to make the head of the snake just a rectangle and well the body just circles. But of course it doesn't work the way I thought it would.

I get these following error messages ''Ellipse cannot be resolved to a type''

and

''The method drawRect(int, int, int, int) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Rectangle)''

The eclipse error message I have no idea why it says that.

But why isn't the drawRect not applicable for the arguements? I mean it's rectangle I am trying to paint.

How do I make this work or is it not possible and I must find another way?

```
Rectangle snakeHead = new Rectangle(5,10,20,30);
Ellipse   snakeBody = new Ellipse (5,10,20,30);

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawRect(snakeHead);
    g.drawOval(snakeBody);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Here is an [article about Java-Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp).

Comment: @gkhaos I am pretty sure you don't understand the question.

Comment: You checked the following parts too, like Java Method Parameters?

Comment: Well, the JDK doesn't have any `Ellipse` class (there is `Ellipse2D` though) so unless you've provided your own the compiler doesn't know that type. That's what the message is telling you. As for the "drawRect(rectangle)" problem: `Graphics2D` has a method `draw(Shape)` which is probably what you're trying to use. Normally the `Graphics` object you get is actually a `Graphics2D` so a cast should be ok (test using `instanceof` to be sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually self-explanatory. You call a drawRect method of the Graphics class:

```java
g.drawRect(snakeHead);
```

The error message says that the method expects four integer arguments, for example

```java
g.drawRect(5, 10, 20, 30);
```

However, you passed a Rectangle object as an argument. You need either make a new method in Graphics class which excepts the Rectangle object as a parameter, or extract the coordinates from snakeHead and pass them to g.drawRect().

Comment: Ok I see,  I assume that method can be used to check for collisions etc? now I have about 3 ways I can do this that is ironicly easier than the way I want it to be like. For example using variables or something for the head instead of an object.